# How to target the wrapper in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I am using two owl carousels on the same page. And need to apply some data to the class of 'owl-wrapper-outer' however the class is added later with javascript and both carousels use it, so I can't just add the changes i want in my css file.

How can I add a new class to the owl carousel wrapper only for one carousel?

I am using owl carousel 1.

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html

Comment: All standard owl carousel code. I could post it here but I don't really see the point in posting code of 1000 lines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional call to the html content.

```
Div class="old-class NEW-CLASS"
```

Then place that new class in the css file to edit the class.

Comment: The class is added afterwards by javascript like I said in my post. So this doesn't work.

Comment: Please place code in fiddle/codepen so we can take a closer look.